# Substitute a value from AWS SSM parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

Working on this POC where i am creating AWS SSM parameter from my Azure pipeline.
Parameter is recreated every time no issues.
But when i call it during CloudFormation Stack creation it does not replace my field.

Clearly the value of the parameter is resolved in Cloudformation log.
[image]

But it is not substituting the value that i am referencing to in my CloudFormation template.
Never used it before but from my research this should be the proper way to use it according to google.
I have removed unnecessary parameters from template for readability.

````
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Dynamo DB test

Parameters:

  ObjectLocation:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: '/unmengexcdev/S3Object'
    Description: Artifact location in S3 bucket

  
Resources:

  GetBlogs:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: 'IaCTesting::IaCTesting.Functions::GetBlogsAsync'
      Runtime: dotnetcore3.1
      CodeUri: !Ref ObjectLocation
      Description: Function to get a list of blogs
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 30
      Role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/DEVOPS_ENGEXC-lambda
      Policies:
        - CUSTOM_ENGEXC-Lambda-Policy
        - AWSLambdaRole
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BlogTable:
            'Fn::If':
              - CreateBlogTable
              - Ref: BlogTable
              - Ref: BlogTableName
      Events:
        PutResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET```
````

Comment: I've never used this feature, but I'm trying to help here. From what the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) says, it seems like you shouldn't use `Ref` function, and you should use `'{{resolve:service-name:reference-key}}'` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that from the start. No luck also. !Ref to parameter seem to be newer and better way.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that I had this working as you have above (and shown on the excellent video on this topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fL3ToMdoXDw). However I started getting the following error:

```
[Parameters.XXXX.Type] 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>' is not one of [...]
```

Implying that AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value is not a valid type.

I tried working out why this was the case and eventually gave up. I switched over to use the resolve syntax and everything works again. See relevant part of my yaml template.file

```
Globals:
 Function:
   Environment:
     Variables:
       ENVIRONMENT: '{{resolve:ssm:environment:1}}'
```

Comment: In my case !Ref worked eventually. 
My problem was that i tried to use the full path to the bucket and object.
AWS didn't like that, so the solution for me was to use intrinsic functions, since my parameter changes every time i run the AZDO pipeline.